# IIS : Test Connection : "Invalid application path"

Tags: web-applications, path, connections

I have created an application in IIS. Selected the application pool it draws from. But when I 'Test Settings...' I get the error:

```
Test Connection
There was an error while performing this operation.
Details:
Invalid application path
```

I'm a GIS Analyst trying to get a Web Map Application running.

Comment: What software are you using that you see this error?

Comment: I am doing this in IIS Manager.

Comment: Invalid application path - this is the clue :P  Are you using an absolute path to the application?